# Subgroups of SO(2) isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and subgroups of O(2) isomorphic to $D_{2n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm looking to show $\mathbb{Z} \leq SO(2)$ and $D_{2n} \leq O(2)$. I've shown $\mathbb{Z}_n \leq SO(2)$ by constructing a subgroup isomorphic to the roots of unity, but I'm not sure how to go from that to $\mathbb{Z}$, or if I need to do something completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\mathbb Z\le SO(2)$, look at the upper-triangle matrices with $1$'s on diagonal.

$D_{2n}\le O(2)$ is by definition of $D_{2n}$ being the symmetric group of the regular $n$-gon.

Comment: For $\mathbb{Z} \leq SO(2)$, wouldn't an upper triangular matrix not work since we need $a^2 + b^2 = 1$ for it to be an orthogonal matrix (with typical matrix lettering).

Comment: I'm saying the matrices of the form $\left(\begin{array}{cc}1&a\\0&1\end{array}\right)$.